# How to stream microphone to speaker in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to stream microphone to speakers simultaneously in a react native project. I've tried the **LiveAudioStream** & **MicStream** packages, but I have no idea how can I directly play the microphone stream.

Can anyone suggest me the best way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this library [react-native-audio-player-recorder library](https://github.com/Shinetechchina/react-native-audio-player-recorder) ? Maybe this let you do both things at same time

Comment: I did, it can't do both at the same time